# SSRS Report parameters cannot pass empty values to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, rdl

I have a SSRS report. When I click button 'View Report', all records are displayed by considering all filters present.

I have dropdown report parameter, which is distinct values of 'Location'. Everything works fine, but when 'Location' has empty values, it fails to work.

When I click button 'View Report', a stored procedure will be called and records are displayed.

My stored procedure is A okay.

The problem is my stored procedure doesn't get any empty values at all from SSRS reports.

Screenshots of dropdown report parameter:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Dropdown in report looks like this:

[image]

When I click button 'View Report', the stored procedure must call like

```
SP_DisplayResults @Location=N',CM,SC'
```

But since blank value is not passed from ssrs report, it is executed like

```
SP_DisplayResults @Location=N'CM,SC'
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Agreed @marc_s, I am not using 'sp' in my sql scripts. I just used here so that people who are reading this question  will know it is a stored procedure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar before by replacing the blank value in the Available Values dataset with a sort of place holder value that is then handled in the stored procedure.

e.g. in your DistinctLocation dataset query do something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE 
WHEN LocationType = '' THEN '(blank)' 
ELSE LocationType 
END as LocationType
FROM Location
```

Then in your SP_DisplayResults stored procedure you can handle the '(blank)' value